# How to convert a String type variable to CFString in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I learned this from iOS tutorial, but it doesn't work

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: NSDictionary!) {
    var mediaType = info.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerMediaType) as String
    var originalImage, editedImage, imageToUse: UIImage

    // Handle a still image picked from a photo album
    if (CFStringCompare(CFStringRef(mediaType), kUTTypeImage, 0) == CFComparisonResult.CompareEqualTo) {
        editedImage = info.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage) as UIImage
        originalImage = info.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) as UIImage

        if (editedImage) {
            imageToUse = editedImage
        } else {
            imageToUse = originalImage
        }

        // Do something with imageToUse
    }
```

It constantly alerts me

> CFStringRef is not constructible with '@lvalue String'

So I tried this:

```
// Handle a still image picked from a photo album
    var temp = mediaType as CFString
    if (CFStringCompare(temp, kUTTypeImage, 0) == CFComparisonResult.CompareEqualTo) {
        editedImage = info.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage) as UIImage
        originalImage = info.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) as UIImage
```

And it alerts me with

> Cannot convert the expression's type 'CFString' to type '$T1'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Swift.String` and `NSString` bridge automatically, and `NSString` and `CFString` can be cast to one another, but you can't (for now?) transitively get all the way from a Swift `String` to a `CFString` without an extra cast or two.

Here's a Swift string, a function that takes a `CFString`, and how to call it by casting to `NSString`:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

func takesCFString(s: CFString) {}

takesCFString(str as NSString)
```

Note you don't need to use `CFStringRef`in Swift (and most of the Swift declarations of `CFString` API don't). The compiler takes advantage of the automatic ARC bridging for CF types that was introduced with Xcode 5 to let you treat those types like Swift (or ObjC) objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "string"
var cfstr:CFString = str as NSString // OR str.__conversion()
```

Comment: Error when using this method: "'NSString is not a subtype of 'CFstring'".  However, the commented portion appears to work.